# Not able to set data in the recycler view

Tags: android

I wanted to set the data(result)into the recycler view, but when i run, the data is not displayed on the screen

```
RPCRequest.OnResponseListener orderListener = new RPCRequest.OnResponseListener<ArrayList<Person>>() {
    @Override

    public void onSuccessResponse(RPCRequest request, ArrayList<Person> response) {
      ArrayList<Person> dups=new ArrayList<>();

            for(int i=0;i<response.size();i++){
     if(compare(response.get(i).getDate(),Person.getInstance().getDate()))
         dups.add(response.get(i));
            }


            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.form);
            View layout=(View) dialog.findViewById(R.id.row);
            layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) dialog.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            toolbar.setTitle(" Duplicates");


            final RecyclerView dupOrders = (RecyclerView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);



            dupOrders.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.setData(dups);
            dialog.show();
```

This is my code where i want to set the data in recycler list view. but when i debug i get the value in data. but its not displayed while executing. Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a LayoutManager for the RecyclerView.
Add this line:

```
dupOrders.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
```

You should probably do this just once, so you might want to make your `dupOrders` variable into a field of your Activity and initialize it and set the LayoutManager in onCreate().